# Substring with greatest ratio

Tags: algorithm, substring

Let's assume I have some sequence containing `{A,B}` and there is at least one occurrence of each letter in a sequence. How to find substring within sequence that fulfill requirements:

- number of A's to number of B's should be highest possible ratio (#A/#B --> max)
- if there are many substring with same ratio we have to return longest possible substring
- finally if there are many of them with same length, we had to return the one with lower beginning index

As output we want index of beginning of found substring and it's length.

Example

```
IN: AAABAA
OUT: index = 0, length = 6 (ratio is 5 : 1)
IN: BABAABBA
OUT: index = 1, length = 4 (ratio is 3 : 1)
```

Any hints how to approach problem?

As a request I'm adding my thoughts:

1. If some two groups of consecutive A's are separated with 3 or more B's there's no reason to test it further. It's quite simple because if we had substring like: `...A{k}BBBA{m}...` ratio is `(k+m):3` whereas `k:1` or `m:1` must give better option
2. I tried also finding all longest substrings of A's in sequence. I thought it would be highly propable that my sequence would be something like `A{N1}BA{N2}BA{N3}` but later on I found it not necesearily true for instance:

   BABAABBAAA

As we can see there are two sequence with same ratio:

1. i=1 length=4
2. i=6 length=4

But as rule 3rd implies I should return the first one wheres as I said my algorithm was based on longest consecutive A's in sequence.

Comment: tell us what you tried. at least the brute force solution with asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath
I've edited orginal post with what I've tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103050/what-exactly-is-the-brute-force-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework, so that is probably not a good question to be answered fully. The hint, however, is to start with simple cases:

1. What happens if you have only one `B` in the sequence?
2. What happens if there are two `B`'s? Assume your sequence contains `x A`'s, then a single `B`, then `y A`'s, then a single `B` again, and then `z A`'s and write some inequalities.
3. Make the reasoning work for all sequences (hint: for any sequence of numbers `a[1] ... a[n]` `(a[1] + ... + a[n])/n <= max(a[1], ... , a[n]`, and the equality occurs only when all the element are equal).

Comment: 1. It's simplest case, whole sequence match to substring
2. This case is easy as well I will have do checking like bracket shows {AAAAB(AAAA}BAAAA)

However when I have 2 B's next to each other it's not neceserilly obvious AAAAAABBAAAAAA - but I think that I'll take longer one or whole if halves are equal.

3. Sorry I haven't understood you at this point.